# How Might We Name AI's Designed to Protect All the Earth?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, alternate-reality, names

<sub>**PROJEKT '** ***VERDANT PALISADE*** **'**</sub>

The year is 2020. A meeting of the UN Security Council is held, disclosing the initial success of a joint project between several member states and handing over authority to the United Nations. This will, in following years, be remembered as the first tests of the AI that would serve as the framework for the several AI's that now defend humanity from all threats — internal or otherwise.

The question is, though, how might these AI's be named? Since the project is an international cooperation, it's difficult to settle on a single name that does not exclude or over-emphasize any one part of human civilization, while also not being boring or difficult to remember or pronounce.

So far, the working names I have for the major 3 AI's are as follows:

- PALATINE_OVERSEER
- DAMASCUS_FORGE
- KHOURUSH_TACTICIAN

And their respective proxies:

- EKATERINA_ADM
- ILHAMJAN_IND
- LEONIDAS_MIL

This current format simply puts their name, an underscore (the computer language they're programmed in doesn't allow spaces in titles), and a title related to their role in the defensive grid. (i.e. DAMASCUS_FORGE, Damascus being the name and Forge being related to their role as the head of industry.)

My main issue is the inconsistency, more than anything. How should the titles work? Should the names be people? Places? Unique (like the original name of the grid's overseer, Satjhari)? And then, who/where gets named after which AI? If they're unique, who comes up with the names? How do these names get approved?

I appreciate any help with this! Since it's the first question on this topic and pretty ill-defined, I'd be happy to answer any questions and provide any needed clarification. And don't be afraid to be adventurous with your ideas! The current format for names I'm using is not a requirement. Thanks! ^^

Comment: This'll get closed as opinion-based here most likely ([meta post on naming](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6125/is-name-choice-on-topic-for-worldbuilding)), but there's a [naming](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/naming) tag and lots of successful questions of this type on [writing.se] our sister site. Make sure to take their tour first as usual.

Comment: (1) There is no link between the lexical rules of a programming language and the names of things in English. (2) The programming language may or may not allow spaces in identifiers, but the English language most definitely does not use the character underscore *at all*. (Until the late 1970s many printing shops didn't even have it.) (3) To understand why the question will be closed, please try to explain why your proposed names are better than Unbending Willow, Feisty Dryas, and Colorless Greenery. (And their proxies, whatever that means, being Willowy John, Dryadic Jack and Greeny Harry.)

Comment: P.S. Names of strategic assets etc. are most often specifically chosen as **not** to give the enemy any hint of their capabilities and funtions. Just as knowing that a person is named Abu Kir or Abu Sir doesn't tell you anything about their height, strength, occupation, education etc.

Comment: from the description of name tag - "This tag is NOT to be used to ask questions of the form "what is the best name...?" which are off-topic."

Comment: Hi @Inpu. This Stack's purpose is to help you develop and consistently use the rules and systems of a fictional world of your own design. Storybuilding, which is off-topic, usually takes the form of plot, circumstances, and character choices/actions. However, storybuilding also encompasses *aesthetics,* which includes "best name for X?" "what should X look like?" and other similar questions about window dressing. We apologize, but this question is off-topic.

Comment: Programming languages have had text storage mechanisms that allow text with spaces in for more than fifty years already. Human-friendly names for pretty much every piece of software will use these text storage mechanisms, and will not be subject to the restrictions of the compilers and other bits of the toolchains used to build the software. Because that would be weird and unnecessary. Your 6 example names already fail your politically-and-linguistically neutral requirements, FWIW.

Comment: I hate to say it, because once I do you know that I'm right and there's no *unknowing it*. The AI would be named AIey McAIface. This is the world we live in. Any attempt to make the name different in your fiction will paint it as unrealistic and overgenerous estimating humanity's intelligence and good taste. It's ok to hate me.

Comment: MolbOrg,  "This tag is NOT to be used to ask questions of the form "what is the best name...?" which are off-topic." - why ?

Answer (score 1):

## With a boring acronym

The UN is an organization composed of lots of different countries with lots of different languages. They don't all see English as the best language.

https://www.un.org/en/about-us/un-system

As such, the UN will likely use boring acronyms to name it, to avoid offending any of the parties contributing money and political power to make the AIs.

United Nations Protective Artificial Intelligence, UNPRA for example.

## The AIs may get their own names.

Through self choice or popular opinion the AIs may get more interesting names that do favor a country.

Answer (score 0):

Their function is their name.

You call them Overseer, Forge, Tactitian etc. A big advantage is that the name "changes" based on the language. If necessary you could use the first letters phonetically as their name in their programming language. Ovee for Overseer, Efo for Forge, Te-a for Tactician etc.